# POSIX/C: chdir() not changing the directory with spaces?

Tags: c, shell, unix, posix, chdir

I am trying to develop a shell in C/POSIX on my Mac OS X. For the `cd` command, I can successfully change the directory of the shell with the `chdir` method in most cases except when the path has spaces in it. For example, a path such as

```
/users/bayesianStudent/desktop
```

correctly changes the directory but the following,

```
/users/bayesianStudent/desktop/Spring\ 2016
```

return error message:

```
No such file or directory
```

However, if I take the same path and use  the regular terminal, it works normally(so nothing is wrong with the path). Following is a dummy program that replicates the issue:

```
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char path[1024];
    char cwd[1024];

    printf("Please enter path:\n");
    gets(path);
    printf("Trying to change the path to %s\n", path );

    int i = chdir(path);
    if( i == 0 )
    {
        printf("sucess\n");
        if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) != NULL)
            fprintf(stdout, "Current working dir: %s\n", cwd);
        else
            perror("getcwd() error");
    }
    else
    {
        perror("Directory not changed: ");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also, since I am developing a shell, I run into same problem with other commands that use file path such as `ls`. For instance, I get a similar message for(when there are spaces but path is correct):

```
execvp("ls", path, NULL);
```

Comment: When you enter the path, are you typing a backslash before the space? If so, don't do that.

Answer (score 2):

As you are not very specific which path you enter into your program, I try to explain what happens:

1. If you issue a shell command like `cd`, the shell interprets the command line and splits it at unescaped whitespace. In your example, you don't want it to split your path name between `Spring` and `2016`, so you escape that space.

   In other words, the shell turns your `/users/bayesianStudent/desktop/Spring\ 2016` into `/users/bayesianStudent/desktop/Spring 2016` and that's what arrives at the program.
2. If you input a path into a program as in

   ```
   printf("Please enter path:\n");
   gets(path);
   ```

   you don't have escaping so you have to enter the path as it is.
   Especially, if you enter `/users/bayesianStudent/desktop/Spring\ 2016`, your program will see the string including the `\` and sees that no such directory exists.